# Install openjdk 8 on Mint 17.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java, linux-mint, openjdk

I am trying to install openjdk 8 on my Mint 17.3
It is based on Ubuntu 14.04 which does not have openjdk 8 in its repositories. Although, I was able to find a link where someone just says that it is possible to install it through 'apt-get install': http://tutorialforlinux.com/2015/12/24/how-to-install-java-openjdk-jre-jdk-on-linux-mint-17-3-rosa-32-64bit-gnulinux/

Can someone confirm that solution? Also if it does not work on yours machine, could you please give me standard way to install openjdk 8 on Mint 17.3?

Comment: That will only work if openjdk-8 is available in the configured repositories for apt. In my installation at least, there's no packages available, so the tutorial suggestions just don't work.

Answer (score 1):

Instructions for installing OpenJDK 8 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS can be found at source.android.com (linked as "Reference")

> For Ubuntu LTS 14.04
>
> There are no available supported OpenJDK 8 packages for Ubuntu 14.04.
>   The Ubuntu 15.04 OpenJDK 8 packages have been used successfully with
>   Ubuntu 14.04.

Reference: https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html